# SQL Server backup cannot restore: The media set has 2 families but only 1 provided. All members must be provided

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I am trying to restore a database backup in new pc but it giving this error:

> System.Data Salclient.SqlEsror: The media set has 2 families but only 1 provided. All members must be provided. (icrosoft.SqlServer.Smo)

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hello Learner_developer. For questions like this, it is best to copy the error message and paste it in your question text.

Comment: Sir I entered the error text

Comment: You know there is a Print Screen Button too, right? It's to the left of your Scroll lock and Pause.Break keys, on the left side on your keyboard. Holding Ctrl while pressing Print Screen will also just capture the active window. As for the error, looks like there should be 2 files, but you have only supplied 1.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because your database backup was stripped and the backup stream was split into two destination files. You are trying to restore from a single backup file. You need both files to restore your database.

For more information on the error, please read this referen [MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968/the-media-set-has-2-media-families-but-only-1-are-provided?forum=sqltools)

OR

1. When you make the backup, change the Backup Set Name.
2. Remove all of the destinations listed, and add 1 new destination.
3. Do a full backup.

It should restore normally